# using emberjs didInsertElement to display two seperate calendars or two instances a jquery fullcalendar plugin object

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, ember.js

I have a single calendar  object displaying fine using jquery fullcalendar and emberjs. However, i need to display a separate second calendar or another jquery fullcalendar instance but the second calendar has so far failed to display. Here is fiddle showing it: http://jsfiddle.net/uUWqf/4/. You will see in the fiddle that i tried calling didInsertElement: function() {} twice, but it still only displaying one calendar.
However, when i use jquery fullcalendar without emberjs, the two separate calendars are displayed: http://jsfiddle.net/CH4qa/2/.

Is there a way to get this to work.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a fork of your fiddle that renders two calendars. http://jsfiddle.net/duHfN/7/

In general, you will have better luck using templates to instantiate views rather than creating view instances and calling append on them. There were a number of other issues with the fiddle, some which I cleaned up.