# How to persist hasMany association in a single Ember.js form using Ember Data & Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, has-many, ember-data

I'm having trouble determining the correct way to persist a hasMany association with a single form using Ember.js, Ember Data and Rails. A Client hasMany Projects. I have a new project form that has two fields: project name and client name. http://cl.ly/image/3z0P0R3M1t2u

I've tried to keep my create logic within the Ember.js *ClientsController* & *ProjectsController*, but will I need to move some of that to the submit action on my *ProjectsNewView*?

**Update:** I've updated my code after finding this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/115). I'm getting closer, but the Rails *ProjectsController* is still not receiving the associated client_id. It is not a part of the params that the controller receives. It still feels like I'm probably not going about this the best way.

**Models:**

*Rails*

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :projects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects
  validates :name, :presence => true
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :client_id

  belongs_to :client

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :client, :presence => true
end
```

*Ember.js*

```
App.Client = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  projects: DS.hasMany('App.Project', { embedded: true })

  validate: ->
    if @get('name') is null or @get('name') is ''
      'Client requires a name.'

App.Project = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  client: DS.belongsTo('App.Client')

  validate: ->
    if @get('name') is `undefined` or @get('name') is null or @get('name') is ''
      return 'Projects require a name.'
    if @get('client') is `undefined` or @get('client') is null or @get('client') is ''
      'Projects require a client.'
```

**Controllers:**

*Rails*

```
class Api::ClientsController < Api::BaseController    
  def create
    @client = Client.find_or_create_by_name(params[:client][:name])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.save
        format.json { render json: @client, status: :create }
      else
        format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entry }
      end
    end
  end
end

class Api::ProjectsController < Api::BaseController
  def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

    respond_to  do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entry }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*Ember.js*

```
App.ClientsController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  createClient: (data) ->
    @transaction = App.store.transaction()
    client = @transaction.createRecord(App.Client, data)

    project_data = data.projects_attributes[0]
    client.get('projects').createRecord(project_data)

    validation_errors = client.validate()

    if validation_errors
      App.displayError validation_errors
      client.destroy()
    else
      @transaction.commit()

App.ProjectsController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  createProject: (data) ->
    @transaction = App.store.transaction()
    project = @transaction.createRecord(App.Project, data)
    validation_errors = project.validate()

    if validation_errors
      App.displayError validation_errors
      project.destroy()
    else
      @transaction.commit()
      App.get('router').transitionTo('projects')
```

**Views:**

*Ember.js*

```
App.ProjectsNewView = Em.View.extend
  classNames: ['form row']
  tagName: 'form'
  templateName: 'projects/new'

  init: ->
    @_super()

  submit: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()

    client = {}
    client.name = @get('client')

    project = {}
    project.name = @get('name')

    client.projects_attributes = []
    client.projects_attributes.push project

    App.router.clientsController.createClient(client)
```

Comment: If no one is answering, you might get better success by pasting the Stackoverflow link in the IRC channel for emberjs and sticking around there for a while after posting the link. I did that a few times and people responded to the Stackoverflow link and solved my issue. I know you put it on twitter, which was where i saw it but try the IRC channel.

Comment: I think this is now possible using the RESTSerializer 's embed_always mapping to persist hasMany which should also work with or without accepts_nested_attributes_for. The link for a sample app on github demonstrating it is below. [The App on Github](https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example) Relevant section of the app demonstrating persisting a hasMany association with a single form [ActiveRecord association showing has_many](https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example/blob/master/app/models/contact.rb) [the rails controller, both models use one controller](https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_

Comment: Thanks for the update @brg. I'll be sure to check out the resources.

Answer (score 1):

@David i am no expert but i was looking at your question again and i think to get the associated client_id, you will have to **call toJSON method** on the RestAdapter and pass it:

```
{associations: true}
```

The links below explain how to do that:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184213/is-there-a-way-to-post-embedded-objects-back-to-the-api-with-ember-data

[Ember-data embedded objects stored as separate objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068373/ember-data-embedded-objects-stored-as-separate-objects)

[Emberjs - unable to query for embedded model or association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124799/emberjs-unable-to-query-for-embedded-model-or-association)

**Update**

Before i answer the question of where in the code to use toJSON, i want to go one step back to something i just observed with the design of your code.

You are trying to create a parentRecord within child record because **Client** is the parent while **project** is the child. If you observe well, [issue-115](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/115) that you linked to, categorically says that the  parentRecord store would be used to create the record. Also if you examine the test in  evenutual [pull-request that was merged](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/b6acfa41c263e7190073992119e94534c222c512) in respect to **issue-115**, you will see it again stated as **Create a child record within the parentRecord**.

But you are doing the reverse, that is **creating  parentRecord within child record**. You need to reverse that.

Also, **on the rails side**, in the  **Client Model**, you called **accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects**, which just like emberjs does only allows you to create **project** records from Client and not vice-versa. All the examples of how to use **accepts_nested_attributes_for** in the [rails guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and this on [nested attributes](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes), show the fields for the child model created from the forms in the parent model.

So both rails and emberjs are in this use case to create parentRecord from child record. This could be why you having the client-id issue. **So reverse your design** and try it again. If it still doesn't send the client-Id. Then you should called toJSON on the Client Model which is the parent association as shown in the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184213/is-there-a-way-to-post-embedded-objects-back-to-the-api-with-ember-data) from the initial links i posted recommending you call **{associations: true}** on toJson in the restAdapter.

```
 App.Client 
 ##
 toJSON: (options={}) ->
   options['associations'] = true
   @_super(options)
```

I hope this helps. Kindly comment back on what worked or did not work, so that others experiencing similar issues, who find this post can know where to start from.

Finally, it wouldn't hurt to create your **rails api** with  [active_model_serializer gem](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers), which is ember-core team's recommended gem for creating **rails api** for ember-data and the RestAdapter. That way you can sideload and embed associations both from the ember side and the rails side.

Comment: Where in my code are you proposing that I use the toJSON method? I'm sorry for needing a little more explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @David, see everything i wrote under the **update** section in response to your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I am in fact using the active_model_serializer gem. I also believe I am creating the child record from within the parent as you described in my ClientsController with `client.get('projects').createRecord(project_data)` am I not?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You are right, sorry I reached the wrong conclusion. What happened was, as I read through the code and got to the lower part, I thought i didn't see that. Anyway, remember to post how you solved it here as i believe this will be mightily useful to many people as emberjs adoption increases. You can also randomly email this question to a few of the emberjs guru's who also use rails, they just might reply you with suggestions. That was how I solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218108/using-emberjs-didinsertelement-to-display-two-seperate-calendars-or-two-instance.

Comment: Well, I haven't actually gotten it working yet as the client_id still does not come through in the params for the Rails ProjectsController. If I do figure it out, I will post how I did.

Comment: @David, may I know if you have any solution yet? Thanks.

Comment: @AnhNguyen I have not attempted to find a solution any time recently. If I jump back onto this problem I will most definitely post my findings.